# Cannot download certain files in any browser

Tags: windows-7, download

I am using windows 7 on my laptop and for some reason certain files such as .exe files will begin to download, proceed to 100% and then disappear.  I try to open them from the download list and they do nothing. When I look at my downloads folder they are not there.

Comment: Sounds like your security software might be removing them.  Without more specific information we can't help.

Comment: @DonRigatone, please [update your post](http://superuser.com/posts/519306/edit) and let us know what AV (anti virus) you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be security software removing files.
The files could have been downloaded to a different location.

Try the "Save to" option to save under a different folder.